# ACL with nested groups

Tags: acl

I need to config a 2 layers group structure

- GROUP 1
- -- GROUP 1.1
- -- GROUP 1.2
- GROUP 2
- -- GROUP 2.1
- -- GROUP 2.2

Enabling a user to manage GROUP 1 contacts, this user will be able also to manage the subgroups contacts (GROUP 1.1 and GROUP 1.2)?

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not fit your scenario, but for others we have been able to provide this by using Relationships to 'join the dots'

- If someone (X) has Permissioned Relationship to Org 1
- and Org 1 has permission to Org 1.1,
- and person Y has permission to Org 1.1
- and if Org 1.1 has permissioned relationship to Z, then
- X will see Y and Z
- Y will see Z

Oh, and you don't need to add any ACLs at all, this is taken care of via this [Fuzion Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls)

May not be quite what you need but may be useful to others who read your ticket and who could switch to having Relationships at the heart of the ACL requirements.

Comment: Thank's petednz, and your scenario can be merged to group?
I mean: if X, Y and Z all belongs to group Gr1, a search on this group will return: X, Y and Z when made by X and will return Y and Z when made by Y?

Comment: It is based entirely on Relationships, so X will see only those folk in the Group who have the relevant the Relationships

Answer (score 0):

You automatically have access to members of all child groups when you have access to the parent group: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/groups-and-tags/#visibility

However, you need additional ACL permissions for each child group if you want to see and modify their child group status.